# How to fix this logic?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a query with 3 variable tables: @result, @order and @stock.
the logic is the stock qty must be allocated by lotsize (here i set=1) to all order based on priority (FIFO). the stock qty must be allocated till zero and the allocateqty must <= orderqty. the problem is one of orders, its allocateqty is over orderqty (priority=7) while other are correct.

```
DECLARE @RESULT TABLE (priority int,partcode nvarchar(50),orderqty int, runningstock int, allocateqty int)
DECLARE @ORDER TABLE(priority int,partcode nvarchar(50),orderqty int)
DECLARE @STOCK TABLE(partcode nvarchar(50),stockqty int)


INSERT INTO @ORDER (priority,partcode,orderqty)
VALUES (1,'A',10),
(2,'A',50),
(3,'A',10),
(4,'A',40),
(5,'A',3),
(6,'A',5),
(7,'A',11),
(8,'A',10),
(9,'A',10),
(10,'A',10);


INSERT INTO @STOCK(partcode,stockqty)
VALUES('A',120)

IF (SELECT SUM(orderqty)FROM @ORDER)<(SELECT stockqty FROM @STOCK)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO @RESULT(priority,partcode,orderqty,allocateqty)
 SELECT priority, partcode,orderqty,orderqty
 FROM @ORDER
END
ELSE
BEGIN
DECLARE @allocatedqty int = 0
DECLARE @Lotsize int=1
DECLARE @allocateqty int = @Lotsize
DECLARE @runningstock int = (SELECT stockqty FROM @stock)

WHILE @runningstock>=0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @priority int
    SELECT TOP 1 @priority = priority FROM @order ORDER BY priority ASC

    WHILE @priority <= (SELECT MAX(priority) FROM @order)
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @orderqty int
        SELECT @orderqty = orderqty - @allocatedqty FROM @order WHERE priority = @priority
         SELECT @allocateqty = CASE WHEN @runningstock > 0 AND @orderqty > 0 THEN @Lotsize ELSE 0 END

        INSERT INTO @RESULT(priority,partcode,orderqty,runningstock,allocateqty)
        SELECT @priority,
               partcode, 
               CASE WHEN @orderqty >= 0 THEN @orderqty ELSE 0 END AS orderqty,
               @runningstock,
               @allocateqty
        FROM @order 
        WHERE priority = @priority

        SET @priority += 1      
        SET @runningstock = @runningstock - @allocateqty
    END
    SET @allocatedqty += @allocateqty
    IF (@runningstock <= 0) BREAK 
 END
 END
select * from @RESULT where priority=7;

SELECT priority,
sum(allocateqty) as allocated
from @RESULT
group by priority
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: Which version of sql server are you using? we may be able to remove the use of `while` all together

Comment: @ughai, sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my reputation not reach 50 so cant add comment.

you said your other order is correct then priority = 7 is also correct. you can compare priority 2 and 4 with 7. its the same thing. i think all of your loop for `orderqty` only reach 10 times where priority 7 got 11 so it will left 1.

Either everything is correct or everything is wrong =x

**EDIT:**

Hi, I found the answer.

Change

```
SET @allocatedqty += @allocateqty
```

to

```
SET @allocatedqty += 1
```

because when using `SET @allocatedqty += @allocateqty`, the last order `@allocateqty` is `0` then it will always make `@allocatedqty = 0` then it will not increase.

Hope this really help you.

EDIT based on @Jesuraja given answer it should be:

```
SET @allocatedqty += @Lotsize
```

Comment: all priority except priority=7 are correct. i also think about loop only 10 times (total count of priority) and priority=7 loop till 11, but how to fix this?

Comment: i not sure what are you trying to achieve? can u explain in detail what you want? you have 10 orders and only have 120 quantity

Comment: 10 orders with total qty=159, stockqty=120, so i need to allocate/share stock to all orders by each time = lotsize=1 till the stock zero. the order qty must <= allocate qty while allocating based on priority (FIFO).

Comment: i come back later lunch time

Comment: since you already have control all the others field in the loop. u can just let '@allocatedqty' += 1. no need depends on the '@allocateqty'.

Comment: I won't try to solve this in a loop. It will perform very worse on bigger workloads. Loops are for interface developers - not for a database developer. ;-)

Comment: I think you need to set `SET @allocatedqty += @Lotsize` instead of `SET @allocatedqty += 1`

Comment: @lonic everyone have their own way of coding. At here they show what they have done and what is their problem and we will try to help them how to solve their problem based on their coding not ours.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not quite sure what you try to achieve with records which will set your stock to 0 or beyond I just can provide this. But it is much better than to run all your orders in a loop. Maybe you'll want to replace your loop.

```
DECLARE @RESULT TABLE (priority int,partcode nvarchar(50),orderqty int, runningstock int, allocateqty int)
DECLARE @ORDER TABLE(priority int,partcode nvarchar(50),orderqty int)
DECLARE @STOCK TABLE(partcode nvarchar(50),stockqty int)

INSERT INTO @ORDER (priority,partcode,orderqty)
--VALUES (1,'A',10),(2,'A',50),(3,'A',10),(4,'A',40),(5,'A',3),(6,'A',5),(7,'A',11),(8,'A',10),(9,'A',10),(10,'A',10); --your orders
VALUES (1,'A',1),(2,'A',2),(3,'A',3),(4,'A',4),(5,'A',5),(6,'A',6),(7,'A',7),(8,'A',8),(9,'A',9),(10,'A',10);

INSERT INTO @STOCK(partcode,stockqty)
--VALUES('A',50) -- your stock
VALUES('A',50)

IF (SELECT SUM(orderqty) FROM @ORDER)<(SELECT stockqty FROM @STOCK)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @RESULT(priority,partcode,orderqty,allocateqty)
    SELECT priority, partcode,orderqty,orderqty
    FROM @ORDER
END
ELSE
BEGIN
            ;WITH dat AS(
                SELECT s.partcode, s.stockqty, o.priority, o.orderqty, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.partcode ORDER BY o.priority DESC) as runningOrder
                FROM @Stock as s
                INNER JOIN @ORDER as o
                        ON s.partcode = o.partcode
            )
            INSERT INTO @RESULT(priority,partcode,orderqty,runningstock,allocateqty)
                SELECT d1.priority, d1.partcode, d1.orderqty, 
                    d1.stockqty - SUM(d2.orderqty) OVER(PARTITION BY d1.runningOrder) as runningstock,
                    CASE WHEN d1.stockqty - SUM(d2.orderqty) OVER(PARTITION BY d1.runningOrder) > 0 AND d1.orderqty > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                FROM dat as d1
                INNER JOIN dat as d2
                        ON d1.partcode = d2.partcode
                        AND d1.runningOrder >= d2.runningOrder

END
select * from @RESULT where priority=7;

SELECT priority,
sum(allocateqty) as allocated
from @RESULT
group by priority
```

Comment: u can try select * from @RESULT from his code remove the priority=7 then you will understand what he want

Comment: mh. I think I don't get it. He just wants to subtract the orders from the stock based on their priority. Doesn't he? 
What does he want to do if he has a stock of 10 and an order of 11. Should the stock be left to 10? or should it go to -1? Should this order be skipped and the next order should be subtracted instead?

Comment: @lonic, in case stock=10 and order=11 => the allocate qty=10 in case there is only 1 order. but if there are many orders the allocate must be shared by qty=lotsize each loop till stock zero, to make sure all orders get the stock allocate. the allocate qty must <= order qty.

Comment: This means you will remove the 10 from the stock and add another order with orderqty = 1 with the same priority?

Comment: @lonic the allocate qty=0 to order=11, so the stock is zero, and the order is pending qty=1 (no action here). this is only one order case. the condition is allocate qty must <= order qty.

Comment: Well I think my brain is dead. I don't get it. :-D in Short... what should happen if order > stock? Should allocateqty be set to 1 in your exampe (stock:10 - order:11 = allocateqty:1???)